# How to measure remaining lithium battery charge accurately (destructively)?

Tags: batteries, measurement

I want to measure the remaining charge in batteries and my requirements may be somewhat unusual. I do **not** need to preserve the charge left in the battery and it doesn't have to be quick. All I want is to measure how much is/**was** left in a battery. It's okay to fully discharge it in the process.

The type of battery I am most interested in is 1/2 AA, 3.6 V, Li‑MnO2, CR14250. "Normal" size AA 3.6V/3.7V, 14500 would also be interesting.

mAh values would be great but I can live with having to sacrifice (discharge) a full battery as reference for relative values. Is there an easy way to do this accurately (+- 10 mAh? +- 1%?) and cheap (< usd 50?) ?

Comment: For energy, discharge it at an *appropriate* rate while integrating the product of voltage and current until you hit a suitable end threshold.  For current capacity just integrate the current.   Very simple in theory, most of the effort is the practical aspects... for example, you need to stop the discharge before an unsafely low voltage is reached.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work. Are there any ready-made devices I can use for this or does it have to be very closely tailored to my battery?

Comment: Take a look at gas gauge ICs from Maxim or TI.  You could probably get an evaluation board from them with a GUI that could be tweaked or set up to do what you want.

Comment: Your better RC hobby chargers typically offer this kind of analysis function.  But for gentle discharge it's also something you would whip up with an Arduino, a power resistor, and a relay or silicon switch for cut-off at the end threshold.

Comment: "destructively" implies you don't care if the battery still functions afterward, is this correct? Not that it matters, as there are simple enough devices to measure discharge conditions, but you might want to rethink that wording.

Comment: @Higemaru By "remaining charge" you may mean "energy" but either way, how much of either depends upon the loading you apply. You will almost always get a smaller total when the discharge rate is faster. Do you have a specified discharge rate? Or does this vary with the battery, in your mind? (I'd tend to want to load the battery down using one, or possibly two, "nominal" load(s) for a particular battery. But I don't know what you care about.) Accuracy is a whole other matter, requiring the ability to trace your measurements back to recognized standards and/or standard references, e.g. by NIST.

Comment: @Felthry "destructively" means the battery does not function afterwards. How can it, if it is out of charge and these are _non rechargeable_ batteries the OP is asking about

Comment: @Felthry Yes, I don't need to have a "useful" battery after measuring. I just meant to say, often people will want to measure and then keep on using the battery. For me that is not the case, I don't care either way. Just as Maple pointed out, I cannot recharge the batteries. Maybe the wording is confusing, that's right.

Comment: I completely agree with @jonk comment above. There are many ways to measure remaining energy. Constant current discharge immediately gives you final number at the end, a simple resistor with current monitor requires integration. But before you go shopping you should figure out what you are doing it for, because "the remaining charge" that you can get out of the battery heavily depends on discharge current.

Comment: @jonk I think that's an interesting point I did not think about. Ideally I would get results like "this battery would have been good for another n weeks in this application". I'm not sure I understand correctly (my fault, my knowledge in this area is quite limited). A greater load will discharge a battery disproportionally fast? If load A discharges my battery in time N, load A/100 will take at least N times 100?

Comment: @Higemaru Yes. A greater load results in less overall accessible energy. The difference, though, isn't easily predictable. One element of that prediction, and it's only one element and not all of them, would be the effective internal resistance of the battery. If you pull more current through that resistance, then there is a greater voltage drop across it and more power lost into heat energy dissipated into the battery itself. This obviously reduces the total usable energy. And there are other effects, as well.

Comment: @Maple I see. Am I correct in assuming, then, that estimating the time a battery can last in a device which uses very little energy over a long period of time (a single CR14250 in 10+ years) is not easy task?

Comment: @jonk I assume the closer to "real world" circumstances I can test a battery the better? For long term (10+ years) that wouldn't be very encouraging. ;-) Seems I'm not looking at a beginner's project..

Comment: @Higemaru Take a look at this [CR14250 datasheet](https://www.powerstream.com/p/CR14250.pdf). Look at the chart in the middle of the page. You should see it provides \$180\:\text{mHr}\$ when loaded with \$100\:\text{mA}\$, \$450\:\text{mAHr}\$ when loaded with \$10\:\text{mA}\$, \$600\:\text{mAHr}\$ when loaded with \$1\:\text{mA}\$, and \$650\:\text{mAHr}\$ when loaded with \$100\:\mu\text{A}\$.

Comment: @Higemaru Testing it according to how it will be used is a good way. A datasheet can only provide a few nominal bits and pieces of information. I treat that information as very approximate -- just a matter of "sizing" and not much more than that. It lets you know if you are even in the right ballpark, or not. It does NOT predict what you can expect out of any particular battery or specific operational situation. A datasheet mostly tells you what range of loads are anticipated by the manufacturer and roughly what life you might get if your loading is near one of those provided in the datasheet.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that estimating it for long period of time is not an easy task. At 10 years the self-discharge of _individual_ cell will come into play more than actual load. Certainly you won't get anywhere close to real numbers by discharging it say, overnight. As @jonk pointed out the datasheet can give you a hint only.